# Is there a ruby-specific alternative to ctags?

Tags: ruby, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Exuberant ctags simply doesn't work properly in some instances.

Using exuberant ctags, I get referred to a completely incorrect definition:

[image: incorrect referral]

`Coordinator#reporter` isn't even used when I run the code, as evidenced by a lack of `first` being printed to the console, and yet ctags is adamant that this is the method referenced by `@configuration.reporter`

I generated my tags with

```
ctags -RV .
```

I'm running Ubuntu `14.04`

Using ruby-mine to find the definition, it works flawlessly:

[image: correct referral]

However, ruby mine is very expensive and not open source.

So is there an alternative to exuberant ctags? A ruby-specific alternative?

Comment: how do you build your tags?  what's the command you run?

Comment: rubymine is not perfect either. Fails to find the correct definition every other time. This is the price you pay for ruby's dynamic nature. Short of actually _running_ your code, there's no bulletproof way of dereferencing names.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev good to know I'm not missing out on programming paradise by not killing my wallet and purchasing for this one feature :P

Comment: @JayTarka: rubymine is awesome, you should totally buy it for all the other cool features. Besides, the name resolution does work half of the time :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Maybe in the future. Vim and ctags will hold the fort for now :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ruby-mine but I can tell you that Ctags doesn't know anything about object type, mixins, inheritance, etc.  From the docs:

> 9. Why do I end up on the wrong line when I jump to a tag?
>
> By default, ctags encodes the line number in the file where macro
>   (#define) tags are found. This was done to remain compatible with the
>   original UNIX version of ctags. If you change the file containing the
>   tag without rebuilding the tag file, the location of tag in the tag
>   file may no longer match the current location. In order to avoid this
>   problem, you can specify the option --excmd=p, which causes ctags to
>   use a search pattern to locate macro tags. I have never uncovered the
>   reason why the original UNIX ctags used line numbers exclusively for
>   macro tags, but have so far resisted changing the default behaviour of
>   Exuberant Ctags to behave differently.

In vim, you can simply run call a tag definition `C-]` and if you ended up in the wrong place, type:

```
:taglist
```

That will display a list of tags and you can pick which file/method definition to jump to.

You can also navigate via `:tnext` and `:tlast` in vim